# How to @Inject in a PhaseListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, phaselistener

I have added a `PhaseListener` to `faces-config.xml`:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.project.NotificationListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

The class seems to be otherwise correct as it is pretty simple.

```
public class NotificationListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Inject
    private MyCDIStuff stuff;

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        this.stuff.doStuff();
    }
}
```

The 'beforePhase' method gets called correctly, however the MyCDIStuff object is null. I tried using annotation `@Singleton` for the class which most likely was incorrect, and it didn't make the injection work either.

Is there a way to inject CDI managed beans in the `PhaseListener`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before JSF 2.2, `PhaseListener`s are not registered as CDI injection targets. Using `@Inject` (and `@EJB`) has effectively no effect in `PhaseListener`s. You'd need to manually grab the CDI managed beans by programmatically evaluating an EL expression referencing the `@Named`'s (implicit) name, or as last resort via JNDI and `BeanManager` which is quite clumsy.

So, if you can't upgrade to JSF 2.2 (which should be compatible with any JSF 2.0/2.1 and Servlet 3.0 compatible web application), then your best bet is programmatically evaluating an EL expression referencing the `@Named` name. Assuming that you've a

```
@Named("stuff")
public class MyCDIStuff {}
```

then this should do:

```
FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
MyCDIStuff stuff = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{stuff}", MyCDIStuff.class);
// ...
```

Comment: I checked about the JSF 2.2. and the answer was 'no', we can't do this. I'll try using the @Named and getting it from the FacesContext.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't go JSF 2.2 your best bet is to use Deltaspike Core.

It offers 
`MyCDIStuff myCDIStuff = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(MyCDIStuff.class, false);`

Deltaspike is how you should get stuff rather then inventing that yourself. For example if you must have the BeanManager (for example to fire an event) then Deltaspike core also offers `BeanManagerProvider`.

http://deltaspike.apache.org/core.html

Comment: I got the answer by BalusC to work. I'll trust that this would do as well, but I'd rather not include any extra libraries within the project, so a "native" solution would be better in this case.

Comment: Of course the native solution is superior. While Deltaspike is an "extra" library it's not exactly obscure. It's from the weld and owb guys and it has some really good stuff

Comment: You can use @JsfPhaseListener from DeltaSpike. You get a standard CDI bean and don't need the JSF config.