# Is it possible to inject a bean to phaselistener when using JSF 2.3, tomcat with weld cdi implementation?

Tags: jsf, cdi, weld, jsf-2.3, phaselistener

I want to inject a `@SessionScoped` and a `@RequestScoped` beans into my `PhaseListener` implementation, but I got `NullPointerException`.

I use tomcat with weld implementation to achieve CDI. I started to migrate JSF 2.2 to 2.3, so I changed to CDI from `FacesContext`.
Well I replaced `@ManagedBean` to `@Named` and any other things to must do during migration like:
- add beans XML to every modules
- add BeanManager to context XML
- delete bean declarations from faces-config.xml
- add SPI `BeanManager` as resource-env-ref to web.xml
How can I inject any bean to `PhaseListener` implementations?

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyHandler implements Serializable {    
..}

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyController extends MyParentController<Example> {
..}

public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

private MyHandler myHandler;
private MyController myController;

@Inject
public void setMyHandler(MyHandler myHandler) {
    this.myHandler= myHandler;
}

@Inject
public void setMyController (MyController myController) {
    this.myController= myController;
}
...

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
myHandler.method()
}
```

`myHandler` injected bean is null in `afterPhase` method.

Comment: I think that it is not a duplicated question. I asked about the injection in JSF 2.3, not in JSF 2.2. My goal is to eliminate all code what getting bean from context via EL expression.

Comment: Did you try field injection?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930241/how-to-inject-in-a-phaselistener BalusC suggests it should work as of JSF 2.2, but i've been unable to `@Inject` something into a Phaselistener using fieldinjection either (using openWebbeans, Mojarra 2.3, CDI API 2.0). Revoked my duplication flag and am interested in the solution. Upvoted therefore.

Comment: @BravoNine Best to put your answer into a response, and mark it as accepted to help others ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I solved the problem... A few things I had to do:

1. I put     beans.xml     into META-INF/, but beans.xml has to be under
   WEB-INF.
2. In     beans.xml     I had to change bean-discovery-mode from "annotated" to
   "all".
3. I forgot to add a class with @FacesConfig(version = Version.JSF_2_3)
   annotation( to enable EL resolution for CDI beans).
4. Also forgot to change faces-config.xml version to 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

1. I put CDI configuration file `beans.xml` into folder `META-INF` instead of `WEB-INF`
2. In `beans.xml` I had to change [bean-discovery-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310388/meaning-of-bean-discovery-mode-annotated-in-cdi-1-1) from "annotated" to "all".
3. I forgot to add a class with `@FacesConfig(version = Version.JSF_2_3)` annotation( to enable EL resolution for CDI beans).
4. Also forgot to change `faces-config.xml` version to 2.3